# Access violation exception was unhandled trying to save an image

Tags: c#, image, emgucv

I'm new to [Emgu CV](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/emgucv/info) and I have encountered an error ("access violation exception was unhandled") trying to save an image. Here is the image path I have tried:

```
C:\\Users\crowds\Documents\Example\Sample.jpg
```

And here is my code. Can anyone help?

```
//Form CameraCapture
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_capture != null)
    {
        captured FF = new captured();
        FF.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}

//Form captured
namespace CameraCapture
{
    public partial class captured : Form
    {
        public captured()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void captured_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var capture = new Emgu.CV.Capture();

            using (var ImageFrame = capture.QueryFrame())
            {
                if (ImageFrame != null)
                {
                    pictureBox1.Image = ImageFrame.ToBitmap();
                    ImageFrame.Save(
                    @"C:\\Users\crowds\Documents\Example\Sample.jpg");
                }
            }            
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CameraCapture CC = new CameraCapture();
            CC.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: access violation exception was unhandled
here's where the error pops

Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = _capture.RetrieveBgrFrame();

Comment: What is `Emgu.CV.Capture();`?  Where does "Emgu" come from?  An access violation in this code is a crash, quite possibly in this code.

Answer (score 2):

First off, there is an extra `"\"` character in your path.  It should be:

```
// Remove at *:        *
// ImageFrame.Save(@"C:\\Users\crowds\Documents\Example\Sample.jpg");
   ImageFrame.Save(@"C:\Users\crowds\Documents\Example\Sample.jpg");
```

Secondly, the exception you're receiving suggests that there is a permissions issue.  By default, you will not be able to save into the `crowds`'s user's folder unless you are running as that specific user.  This may be related to the typo above, but is also potentially due to running under the wrong account.

> access violation exception was unhandled here's where the error pops Image frame = _capture.RetrieveBgrFrame();

This suggests that the executing user may not have permissions to access the image capture device.

Comment: I did remove the extra "\" character but I'm still having the same error..
can you suggest a better way on saving image in a particular folder?

Comment: when i open the folder, the image is saved though..
but the program stops running because of the error

Comment: Is there a way to fix this error? Or can you suggest a method that will fix this?

Comment: A permissions issue??  Surely you've seen unmanaged code crash with an AccessViolationException before?